# Rest api additonal NULL WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have found two links on this issue associated with WordPress, but none of them worked.

I have code like this:

```
<?php
    /*
        Plugin Name: Test API
    Version: 0.4.2
    Author: FP
  */

  function test_api()
  {
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    echo "(N)(U)(L)(L) TEST";
  }

  add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
      register_rest_route('my-api/v2/', '/test/', array(
        'methods' => GET,
        'callback' => 'test_api'
      ));
    }
  );
```

And after I visit my API endpoint I am always getting additional null at the end. I appears every time (if I use `json_encode()`, if i put my own text, etc., as You can see it is not connected with `global $wpdb` (or maybe I don't know something?)).

```
(N)(U)(L)(L) TESTnull
```

My script is written as `UTF-8` file.
Other WordPress built-in API endpoints work fine (don't print this annoying `null`).

My API endpoints are registered from "MUS-USE plugin" (wp-content/mu-plugins).

Thank You in advance for Your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `exit()` function in the end of the echo statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `return` instead of `echo` as it is in [handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#bare-basics)